# combine translate and position absolute issue

Tags: html, css, css-position, transform

I would like to position `.child` in the bottom right corner of `.parent` given the following html:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="moved">
       <span class="child">Hi</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

So far it is easy, but the problem I have is that I need to `translate` the `.moved` element too

```
transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);
```

Now, all positioning of `.child` is relative to `.moved`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pdf7z4hp/7/)

So the question is if it is somehow possible to position `.child` relative to `.parent` in this situation ?

Comment: What is the class moved used for? is it nog possible to place the child as sibling of moved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because `transform` (with a value different than `none`) creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), so the `.child` position is now related to the `.moved` element, but you could use a negative margin instead , e.g. `margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/o6hsknnw/

---

The final result is visually the same of using `transform: translate3d(-10px, -10px, 0);` (anyway this layer is no longer promoted to the `GPU`)

[image]